# Angular : SetData to HighChart widget from an array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, highcharts

i'm using under my ANgular component a **highchart** widget :

**DEMO OF THE CHART :** https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend

from the documentation , using it is like that :

```
Highcharts.chart('divChart', {
          chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
          },
          title: {
            text: this.nb
          },
          tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
          },
          plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              showInLegend: true
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
              name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
              y: 56.33
            }, {
              name: 'Chrome',
              y: 24.03,
              sliced: true,
              selected: true
            }, {
              name: 'Firefox',
              y: 10.38
            }, {
              name: 'Safari',
              y: 4.77
            }, {
              name: 'Opera',
              y: 0.91
            }, {
              name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
              y: 0.2
            }]
          }]
        });
```

But since am loading dynamically the datat ( chrome , firefox ...) , 
i have now a set fo key/ value data indicationg each browser with its value :

```
  browsers: {[key: string ]: number } = {};
```

**for example my browsers list contains :**

chrome (name) **->** 60 (value)

firefox **->** 30

edge **->** 10

....

i wanna inject my browsers list values dynamically to the data of the chart , and not mannually , since my list may contain numerous values.

i think there were some methode called **setData** , but i don't know if it's usefull.

**Ideas ?**

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/charts)

Comment: You could use both `Series.setData` and `Series.update` functions to change chart's data. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u80Lcvf9/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is setData function
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData

but after you need to update chart http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update

Comment: After using setData() the update is not required. setData() has arguments (redraw and updatePoints) that control the updating process.